# Cannot find FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy in iOS Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, caching, sdk, token

I need to get the Facebook access token of the users of my app and save it in a local storage so that I can make Graph calls on their behalf without having to log them in every time. 
In the [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/token-cache) (iOS platform) documentation it says that I have to override some methods of the *FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy* class however in the latest SDK that I have downloaded this file along with SESSION files don't exist. (I made sure to download the latest SDK).
However, there is a header file in the FBSDKCoreKit.framework called *FBSDKAccessToken* and *FBSDKAccessTokenCacheV4* but I don't seem to find the same methods that I am supposed to override.

Has anyone implemented such scenario with the latest Facebook SDK for iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] after successful login.

U can use it in this way :

```
 NSLog(@"App Id :%@",[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].appID);
 NSLog(@"Token String :%@",[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString);
 NSLog(@"User Id :%@",[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].userID);
 NSLog(@"Token Refresh Date :%@",[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].refreshDate);
```

Refer To : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKAccessToken/